# Emacs: Set fill-column in Change Log Mode

Tags: emacs, mode, autofill, changelog, major-mode

Very specific question that I hope is not too dumb.

`(setq-default fill-column 120)` sets the width of the buffer fill to 120 columns. Default for me otherwise is 74.

This command, when put in my `.emacs` file, works for all major modes I use (C++, Perl, etc). However, it seems not to affect the Change Log major mode (`change-log-mode-hook`). Do you know how I can set the `fill-column` for this mode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you have to set it (I'm just making sure you got this part right):

```
(defun my-change-log-mode-hook ()
  (setq fill-column 120))

(add-hook 'change-log-mode-hook 'my-change-log-mode-hook)
```

Secondly, you have to make sure that there is no **directory local variables** setting that overrides this. For example, when editing the source code of Emacs itself, fill-column will be set to 74 for **change log mode** and 70 elsewhere, overriding the value you specified in µour hook. These are defined in files named `.dir-locals.el` and can be place in or above the directory that contains the edited file.

Comment: Great, that works, thank you. In general, why do I need to `add-hook` when I already set the default value with `(setq-default fill-column 120)`?

Comment: Because `change-log-mode` explicitly sets the variable, hiding the global variant of it. I guess that you could have solved this by using `kill-local-variable` in your hook.